Change Hyper-V IPv6Connectivity
I am trying to test IPv6 on a Hyper-V VM instance in Windows 10. IPv6 is enabled on my network, and working on my host machine (e.g, ping -6 ipv6.google.com is fine). However, in my VM, ping -6 does not work for global unicast addresses (link-local addresses to interfaces on my local network work fine) and I can not load ipv6.google.com in a browser. (All IPv4 addresses work fine on the VM, the internet is accessible.)
In PowerShell on my host machine, I get the following (with my Wifi's Name replaced with <Name>; 'HVS' is a custom name for a Virtual Switch created for my Hyper-V instance, configured for External network with my wireless NIC):
host get-netconnectionprofile
Meanwhile my VM displays:
VM get-netconnectionprofile
Despite my NetworkCategory already being set to Private, I was hoping the 'Accepted Answer' to this question might help, but it seems resetting to Private has no effect on the value of IPv6Connectivity. I am presuming that IPv6Connectivity's value of LocalNetwork is the source of my problem (to be fixed by setting to Internet), but perhaps I am confusing cause and effect.
Is there a way to modify the IPv6Connectivity value directly in our network connection profile? Is there a step I missed to enable IPv6 support on my Virtual Switch? Could this possibly be an issue with my network adapter (this seems unlikely to me, considering everything else is working)?

"modify the IPv6Connectivity value directly" – Are you sure you aren't confusing cause and effect here? The profile doesn't give you connectivity, it reports what connectivity is available.
